# Why does this create an infinite loop

Tags: c, loops

Consider the following C program:

```
int number;
int sum;
char i;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
while (i != 'q')
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum = number + number;
}
sum = number + number;
printf("The sum is %d", sum);
```

Why does this goes into an infinite loop? I don't see any error in the code.

Comment: I do not see where `i` is used in the loop body?

Comment: You never assign or modify i anywhere.

Comment: I think you forgot to add some code after inputting `number` to input `i` inside the loop.And you also forgot to initialize `i`.

Comment: `i` has garbage value, moreover it doesn't change anywhere in the loop.

Comment: so what should i do? i want the program to terminate when the character 'q' is enteres

Comment: @user5032369 what is your purpose actually?

Comment: Voting to close this as simple typo.

Answer (score 3):

`i` is uninitialized. When you check the condition

```
while (i != 'q')
```

anything can happen(Undefined Behavior) because you are checking an uninitialized variable. Moreover, you don't change the value of `i` in the loop. How and why do you expect the condition to become false?

---

`scanf` with `%d` will not scan `char`s. And your code dosen't make much sense anyway. It might make more sense if you tell us what it needs to do.

I think you want this:

```
char number;
int sum = 0;
printf("Enter a number (enter 'q' to exit): ");
scanf("%c", &number);
while (number != 'q')
{
    sum += number-'0';
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%c", &number);
}
printf("The sum is %d", sum);
```

If you are wondering why and what `-'0'` does, you need to have a look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). Each character has its own integer value as seen in the ASCII table.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: How are we supposed to know that? We cannot read your mind. I have provided some code in my answer. Is it what you want?

Comment: Your should probably add that your code is now adding single digits instead of numbers, what seems to be what the OP wants.

Comment: ok see, i want the program to terminate when the character 'q' is entered

Comment: @DanielJour Yes. Waiting for OP to confirm that this is what the OP wants....

Comment: @user5032369 Does the program need to sum up all the values until `'q'` is entered? If so, doesn't the code I've provided suit your needs?

Comment: thank you for the advice, i got some ideas from your code but i didnt use it

Answer (score 2):

First you do not initialize `char i;` and leads to undefined behavior, then in your loop you never modify:

```
while (i != 'q')
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum = number + number;
}
```

This code makes no sense. When do you expect `i` to become `'q'`?

Answer (score 0):

The code is creating an infinite loop because you are using `while (i!='q')`.
Here you haven't initialized the value of `i`, as result the compiler sets a default value to the `char i`, which is not equal to 'q'.
Hence, whenever you are checking the condition in `while loop` it comes out to be true. Therefore a continues loop is formed.
**To improve**
You can improve it by setting an input for character `i` in your program. Or change the condition to any thing else from your program. One solution is:--

```
 int number;
int sum;
char i;
printf("Enter a number: ");
scanf("%d", &number);
while (i != 'q')
{
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    sum = number + number;
    printf("Press q to terminate: ");
    scanf("%c", &i);
}
sum = number + number;
printf("The sum is %d", sum);
```

Comment: Let me know if my answer satisfies your question or not.......

Comment: thank you, i got some ideas from your code, it was very helpful

Comment: ok....All the best for your coding.....and let me know if any further help is required ok....I delighted by helping you....

Comment: how to find out how many times the program has looped?

Comment: @user5032369 You can set a counter as int count=0; in the looping statement and can get the answer of loop count whenever you want from the count variable....ok..dear

Comment: This is wrong. The compiler is not setting any default value. It's undefined behaviour, the value could be anything and change from run to run.

Comment: @DanielJour you are right....My main intention was to say that the value of **i** is never going to be **'q'** ...Am I not correct here?

Comment: It actually could be `'q'` on some run (though the probability is very small).

Comment: @DanielJour yes I got your point......thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all i is uninitialized and moreover inside the loop the value of i is not either initialized or changed.